Call IPyhon functions of ipynb in vscode

I try to run javascript code
%%script node
IPython.notebook.get_cell(1).get_text()

I can ran this well in jupyter lab with IPython. But failed in vscode.
Seems the IPython is not installed in nodejs env. How can i do it in vscode?
I want to run IPython javescript in vscode. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
